# Issue after upgrade from 1.8 to 1.9.4 : Numeric value out of range

Tags: magento-1.9, error, upgrade

I just upgraded magento from 1.8 to 1.9.4, but I get this error below. I tried to change the type of attribute_id from smallint to bigint but then I get this error "Error on rename of './magento/#sql-65cb_4e6d' to './magento/eav_attribute' (errno: 150)".

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
    a:5:{i:0;s:567:"Error in file: "/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/upgrade-1.6.2.0.5-1.6.2.0.6.php" - SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 167 Out of range value for column 'attribute_id' at row 1, query was: INSERT INTO `eav_attribute` (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_code`, `backend_model`, `backend_type`, `backend_table`, `frontend_model`, `frontend_input`, `frontend_label`, `frontend_class`, `source_model`, `is_required`, `is_user_defined`, `default_value`, `is_unique`, `note`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";i:1;s:994:"#0 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(644): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.6.2.0.1', '1.6.2.0.7')
#2 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.6.2.0.1', '1.6.2.0.7')
#3 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/Mage.php(687): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/xxxxx/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
```